# Como detectar se o navegador aceita eventos xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, eventos, xmlhttprequest

É o seguinte, gurizada, para deixar meu objeto compatível com navegadores antigos (senão me xingam) eu criei um novo problema. É difícil desviar o caminho de acordo com a versão do navegador porque não era tão padronizado, os navegadores aceitavam um recurso e outro não, então fiz o seguinte:

```
var reqEngatilhar = function(){
    este.concluido = false;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(reqTimeout, este.timeout);
    if(este.Request.hasOwnProperty("onload")){
        este.Request.addEventListener("error", reqErro, true);
        este.Request.addEventListener("progress", reqMon, false);
        este.Request.addEventListener("abort", reqAbort, false);
        este.Request.addEventListener("load", reqFim, false);
        console.log("$Http reqEngatilhar usando eventos...");
    } else {
        este.Request.onreadystatechange = function (e) { reqSwitch(e); };
        console.log("$Http reqEngatilhar usando onreadystatechange...");
    }
}
```

Esta funçãozinha define os eventos dentro do meu objeto quando muda o estado da requisição xmlhttprequest (onde este=this fora da função). Mas alguns navegadores não aceitam os eventos via addEventListener, então ele define onreadystatechange que fará a "distribuição" chamando a função certa.

O problema é o teste este.Request.hasOwnProperty("onload") que está funcionando apenas para o Safari (meu site só abre no Safari kkkkk).

Então eu pergunto: qual a forma correta (ou melhor possível) de detectar se o navegador aceita os eventos xmlhttprequest via addEventListener?

Comment: Porque não usas `on...` para todos? qual são os browsers que queres suportar? IE7?

Comment: Eu tenho usado o MDN como referência, e ao que parece usar addEventListener é a tendência. IE7 não me interessa, mas mesmo o IE9 dá uns problemas. Eu fiz essa função porque deu problema onde não deveria, mas não anotei o navegador/versão - falha minha.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest && !(window.ActiveXObject)) {
    try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        req = false;
    }
} else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // Se for IE usa o control ActiveX
    try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            req = false;
        }
    }
}
return req;
```

Referência completa: https://github.com/pmcfernandes/r/blob/master/Linq.js

Comment: Essa resposta não tem a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: Estou a exemplificar como ficar o código funcionar para todos os browsers. Penso que se a pessoa for no mínimo inteligente vai tirar partido disso. O stack não é um site de fixes mas de ajuda para corrigir e escrever código existem outros sites como o freelancer